# Rails 7, many to many relationship, create action inserts duplicate values when using collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, many-to-many, collection-select

I'm working on a Rails 7 app. I have a form for creating `companies`, each company can have multiple `verticals`. I'm using `form.collection_select` in the template to let users select one or many verticals. For some reason the create action tries to add the selected verticals twice. I've added a validation to not make that possible.

My relationships looks like this:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :company_verticals, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :verticals, through: :company_verticals
```

```
class Vertical < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :company_verticals
  has_many :companies, through: :company_verticals
```

```
class CompanyVertical < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :vertical

  validates_uniqueness_of :vertical_id, scope: :company_id // causes rollback
```

The relevant parts of my companies controller looks like this:

```
 # POST /companies or /companies.json
 def create
   @company = Company.new(company_params)
   respond_to do |format|
     if @company.save
       # never reaches here since validation kicks in

def company_params
  params.require(:company).permit(<...>, vertical_ids: [])
end
```

And my form looks like this

```
<%= form_with(model: @company, url: [@user, @company]) do |form| %>

  ...
   <%= form.collection_select :vertical_ids, Vertical.all, :id, :name, { label: "Label" }, { multiple: true, class: input_classes } %>
```

When submitting the form I get the following output in the terminal:

> ↳ app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:30:in `block in create' CompanyVertical Exists? (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "company_verticals" WHERE "company_verticals"."vertical_id" = $1 AND "company_verticals"."company_id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["vertical_id", 2], ["company_id", 16], ["LIMIT", 1]] ↳ app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:30:in` block in create'
> CompanyVertical Create (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO "company_verticals" ("company_id", "vertical_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["company_id", 16], ["vertical_id", 2], ["created_at", "2022-11-27 20:16:57.465067"], ["updated_at", "2022-11-27 20:16:57.465067"]]
> ↳ app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:30:in `block in create' CompanyVertical Exists? (4.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "company_verticals" WHERE "company_verticals"."vertical_id" = $1 AND "company_verticals"."id" != $2 AND "company_verticals"."company_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["vertical_id", 2], ["id", 52], ["company_id", 16], ["LIMIT", 1]] ↳ app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:30:in` block in create'
> CompanyVertical Exists? (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "company_verticals" WHERE "company_verticals"."vertical_id" = $1 AND "company_verticals"."company_id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["vertical_id", 2], ["company_id", 16], ["LIMIT", 1]]
> ↳ app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:30:in `block in create'
> TRANSACTION (0.7ms)  ROLLBACK

If I remove the validation (`validates_uniqueness_of :vertical_id, scope: :company_id`) it won't validate but the company will end up with duplicate verticals.

Any idea why this happens?

I'm using the same html template in my update method, but there it works fine.

**Update**

Params that gets passed to controller:

```
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "company"=>{"name"=>"Test", "registration_number"=>"12345", "vat_identification_number"=>"12345", "url_name"=>"test", "bio"=>"", "vertical_ids"=>["", "1", "2", "3"], "contact_information_attributes"=>{"email"=>"", "phone_number"=>""}, "user_id"=>"1", "address_attributes"=>{"country_id"=>"1", "street_address"=>"Test", "city"=>"test", "zip_code"=>"test"}}, "commit"=>"Skapa företag", "user_id"=>"1"}
```

Generated HTML:

```
<input name="company[vertical_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" autocomplete="off">

<select multiple="multiple" name="company[vertical_ids][]" id="company_vertical_ids">
  <option selected="selected" value="1">Vert 1</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="2">Vert 2</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="3">Vert 3</option>
  <option value="4">Vert 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you add the web console before the actual commit? The portion that shows the params being passed to the controller? Also the actual generated HTML of the relevant part of the form might help.

Comment: @Beartech I've updated my question to include parameters and generated HTML.

Comment: Where is that hidden input coming from above the collection select coming from?

Comment: @Beartech Not sure actually. Using 

`<%= form.collection_select :vertical_ids, Vertical.all, :id, :name, { label: "label text" }, { multiple: true, class: input_classes } %>`

For the multi-select. Haven't added that hidden field myself.

Comment: Oh, I think the multiple: true might cause that.

Comment: Can you check the value of `@company` and `company_params` and run `@company.valid?` then check `@company.errors` after `@company = Company.new(company_params)`? because  I don't have this problem.

Comment: @kevinluo201 `puts("valid: ", @company.valid?)` prints `true` before `@company.save` is called. Strange thing it works in my update method with the same form.

Comment: @Anders, I'm guessing there is an `after_save` or `after_create` callback you didn't notice in `CompanyVertical` because it has `company_verticals"."id" != $2` in your second validation SQL and it looks like it's not a uniqueness validation.

Comment: Something is missing from the code you have posted. With the parameters you have posted above the request will be successful. I've created a single file with your example https://gist.github.com/cristianbica/489ebafb0e5c69e78984f8e7f083b982 and it passes. The only way the request fails is if some vertical ID is passed twice (in the logs you've posted you can see it checks if vertical_id 2 exists, it adds it and then it checks again). Can you replicate the issue with the single file rails app I've posted?